# How should the following notation be read?

Tags: functions, notation

In the opening chapter of `foundations of optimization’ by Guler it states:
$$f:I=(c,d) \to \mathbb{R}$$

Should this be interpreted as $I$ is a function over the open interval $(c,d)\;$ that maps to the real number line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means $I$ is an open intervall with $I = (c,d)$. Then $f$ is a function $$f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
In your book there probably will be more clarification about the open intervall $(c,d)$

Comment: Thanks. I did look for clarification in the book but didn’t see any.

Comment: I looked it up for you. It is in the introduction "We  treat  the  calculus  of  scalar-valued  functions $ f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ or  vector-valued functions (maps) $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$, where $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$"

Answer (score 1):

It is a very interesting question to me since I have faced the same problem when I was first introduced to advance calculus. Here is a couple of examples and pronunciation that I learned.

$1.$ $f:I=(a,b)\to X$ :  $f$ is a mapping from $I$ to $X$. Here domain and range is known.

$2.$ $a\mapsto f(a)$ : $f$ is a mapping that maps $a$ to $f(a)$. Here domain and range is unknown

$3.$ $a\mapsto Xa$ : There is some map that takes $a$ to $Xa$. Here domain and range is unknown also the function itself is unknown.

$4.$ $f:X\subset Y \to A\subset B$ : $f$ is a map from $X$ to $A$. Simply!

Comment: For "$a$ maps to $f(a)$" normally another kind of arrow is used: $a \mapsto f(a)$.

Comment: Thanks! This notation is more popular than the one I used! I forgot to use that.